# Sails.js delete scripts from layout

Tags: sails.js

when add these scripts to layout.ejs

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

i run sails lift this erase the previous scripts and add

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
    <!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

i'm new in this awesome framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sails looks for tags `<!--SCRIPTS-->` and `<!--SCRIPTS END-->` and it puts dependencies in it.
In fact it gets all Js files from `/asserts/js` and link them in that place. In production it will also minify all Js into one file.

If you don't want that you can disable tasks in grunt, or add your scripts to: `/tasks/pipeline.js` into `jsFilesToInject`